# How to load sharded bigquery tables as DBT source

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I am new to dbt and in BigQuery I can query partitioned tables in a large dataset by using an asterix.
e.g.

```
select * from x.ads_d_*
```

The asterix represents the year and month e.g. 202211.
How do I create a source for this in dbt. If I use the code-gen package it creates a table for every month but I do not want to update it every month.

I read about incremental datasources but I am not sure if this is what I need? Can somebody point me in the right direction.

Adding the asterix in .yml sources definition does not seems to work.

schema.yml

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: funnel_io_ads
    tables:
      - name: ad
      - schema: ad_d_*
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Some context

To be clear about an important distinction - BigQuery supports two different kinds of 'table broken down into chunks by date':

1. date-sharded tables
2. partitioned tables

([here are the relevant docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard) and [you can read an explainer here](https://mark-mccracken.medium.com/bigquery-date-sharding-vs-date-partitioning-cee3754f7900))

#### Three problems

The `*` syntax can be used with date-sharded tables. However, you *don't* have a date-sharded table. BigQuery will automatically collate tables in the same dataset with the same suffixed name **if and only if** the suffix is of the form `YYYYMMDD`.

Your suffix is of the form `YYYYMM`, so BigQuery does not recognise this as a single date-sharded table collection. That's the first reason it isn't working for you.

The second reason (once you've sorted that out) is that you need to use backticks around your sharded tablename:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ad_d_*`
```

There is a third problem, which I imagine will be causing you confusion.

Judging by the icons in your screenshot, what you seem to have done is create many *partitioned tables* (each one has the right icon to be a partitioned table). This is incorrect usage: a partitioned table should be a single table with a partitioning key, which BigQuery will use 'behind the scenes' to split the data into chunks.

#### Solutions

There are several approaches to sort this out.

1. create a single partitioned table `ad_d`. You could configure this with ingestion-time partitioning, or if the table contains a date/timestamp column  you can use time-unit partitioning with this column as the partitioning key. You could configure this to use 'monthly' partitioning, since this seems to be what you want. In DBT, you can then use this single table as a source in the standard way.
2. create a true set of date-sharded tables. You need the tables in your BigQuery dataset to be (a) regular tables, not partitioned tables and (b) the proper suffix, e.g. `ad_d_20180201` rather than `ad_d_2018`. It doesn't matter if you only actually have one per month.

**The first of these approaches is recommended.**

However, if you have some limitations that force you to use the latter, you can configure a DBT source as follows:

```yaml
sources:
  - name: funnel_io_ads
    database: <your GCP project ID>
    schema: funnel_io_ads
    tables:
      - name: ad
        identifier: ad_d_*
```

You will then be able to reference this source as `{{ source('funnel_io_ads', 'ad') }}` in DBT models.

Comment: Thanks, Yesterday I indeed noticed I have a sharded database which is also partitioned. This was a limitations of the tool creating it in the past. Luckily this issue has been solved and I can rebuild the dataset. I will try querying it tomorrow or beginning next week. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can add the field

```
- identifier: ad_d_*
```

instead of "schema"

For reference, I found [this project](https://github.com/Velir/dbt-ga4/blob/main/models/staging/ga4/src_ga4.yml) that is using this.

Comment: That does not seem to work and gives me the error `invalid source config is given`and `at path ['tables'][1]: 'name' is a required property`

Comment: the tables are sharded on date which ga4 uses partioned tables as far as I know. Maybe that is the issue